# regex top level contents from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please help, my regular expression skills fail me. I have the following string:

```
username|email_address|phone_numbers[number]profile[title|addresses[id]]
```

I want to be able to extract any data between square brackets, but not where that data is a subset of an already extracted set. So any nestings should be left as part of the parent's extracted string.

In the above example I'd have extracted two parts:

```
"number"
"title|addresses[id]"
```

Note how the [id] isn't extracted as it's part of a lower level dataset.

I've been attempting to do this with preg_match, but think I may have to resort to iterating over each character in the string.

Comment: That's really oddly formatted data. Where is it coming from? Also, yes, you're going to have to iterate the string (or otherwise parse it) as regex can't match brace pairs, let alone nested ones

Comment: @Bojangles: Of course it can. Regexes are not limited to regular languages any more. They haven't been for decades and still people keep peddling the old myth "regex can't handle nesting"...

Comment: @Tim Can you cite that? All I've found in my quick bit of research is that .NET can do it, but nothing else can due to regexes being represented as a finite automaton which has no memory of it's state

Comment: @Bojangles: My answer would be an example, [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) contains more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regex solution:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(?<=\[)     # Assert that the previous characters is a [
      (?:         # Match either...
       [^[\]]*    # any number of characters except brackets
      |           # or
       \[         # an opening bracket
       (?R)       # containing a match of this very regex
       \]         # followed by a closing bracket
      )*          # Repeat as needed
      (?=\])      # Assert the next character is a ]/x', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

A sad truth is that regular expression cannot handle bracket matching, because regular expression don't have memory. (It's equivalent to [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata))

To achieve what you want you'll have to write a small parser by yourself (I think), using stack can solve the problem ;)

The basic idea using stack to solve the problem is that.. every time you see an [ you'll push stack, and every time you see an ] you'll pop stack and retreat the string you got since the [ you saw last time.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: "Regular" expressions can't. PHP's regex flavor can handle recursion just fine using `(?R)`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small parser to achieve the desired results:

**Code:**

```
$data = 'username|email_address|phone_numbers[number]profile[title|addresses[id]wut]aaa[another test] aaand another one [which is [more] c[omplexer]t[h[an]] the others]';
print_r(parse($data));

function parse($string, $s1='[', $s2=']'){
    $c1 = $c2 = 0;$s = 1;
    $l = strlen($string);
    $array = array(array(), array());
    for($i=0;$i < $l;$i++){
        if($string[$i] == $s1){
            $c1++;
            $array[0][$c1] = $i;
        }elseif($string[$i] == $s2){
            $c2++;
            $array[1][$c2] = $i;
            if($c1 == $c2){
                $results[] = substr($string, $array[0][$s], $array[1][$c2] - $array[0][$s] + 1);
                $s=$c1+1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [number]
    [1] => [title|addresses[id]wut]
    [2] => [another test]
    [3] => [which is [more] c[omplexer]t[h[an]] the others]
)
```

**[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FXAijQ)**