# Regex: Match text from nested parenthesis.

Tags: regex, perl

How regex will give me output

`se,dc(fr(lo)),km(ji)(hn),...` from a string `az(se)(dc(fr(lo)))(km(ji)(hn))...`

Could anyone tell me how to write regex for obtaining text between the parantheses so that I can achieve the result like the one above without using any external package/library as it is only for learning purpose.

Comment: Headline is NOT for posting the question itself.

Comment: What you want is to match the top level of parenthesis, which is slightly different than [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16415558/) so we can make use of [the great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16420841/) provided there and create [the following regex](http://regex101.com/r/gN9iW4). Have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite the classic example for **recursive regex**:

```
\(((?:[^()]++|\((?1)\))*+)\)
```

### Explanation

Let us break down the regex:

```
\(              # Literal (
(               # Start of capturing group 1
  (?:           # Start of non-capturing group
     [^()]++    # Match characters other than ()
     |          # OR
     \((?1)\)   # Recursively match bracketed () content
  )*+           # End of non-capturing group, and repeat the whole group zero or more times.
)               # End of capturing group 1
\)              # Literal )
```

The 2 literal brackets `()` at the beginning and the end are to make sure we match the text inside the bracket. Without them, it will instead match portions of text with balanced brackets.

The `(?:[^()]++|\((?1)\))*+` part describes the pattern inside a pair of brackets:

- There can be sequences of non-bracket `()` characters
- Or bracketed `(...)` portion, which starts with `(`, followed by `(?:[^()]++|\((?1)\))*+` (due to the effect of `(?1)` *subroutine call*) and ends with `)`.

And there can be 0 or many instances of non-bracket sequences and bracketed `(...)` portions interleaved with each other.

The `(?1)` is called *subroutine call*, which allows you to match with sub-pattern delimited by capturing groups. In this case, since `(?1)` is inside the capturing group 1, it creates a recursive effect.

### Demo

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/4PN6um)

```
my $str = "az(se)(dc(fr(lo)))(km(ji)(hn))(()aaa(()())(ff(dd)aa))";
my @arr = $str =~ /\(((?:[^()]++|\((?1)\))*+)\)/g;
print join("\n", @arr)
```

Output

```
se
dc(fr(lo))
km(ji)(hn)
()aaa(()())(ff(dd)aa)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter version of nhahtdh's regex:

```
\(((?:[^()]++|(?R))*+)\)
```

You can avoid repeating the literal parenthesis by recursing to the whole expression (`(?R)`) instead of the sub expression (`(?1)`). Otherwise it's the same.

Used as:

```
my @list = $str =~ /\(((?:[^()]++|(?R))*+)\)/g;
```