# A regular expression that can split a string having nested brackets that are the same

Tags: regex, parsing, clojure

I know that regular expression can be used to write checkers that check for pairs of start and end symbols for brackets:

eg. `a.[b.[c.d]].e` yield values `a`, `[b.[c.d]]`, and `e`

How can I write a regular expression that can figure out start and end brackets that are the same symbol

eg. `a.|b.|c.d||.e` would yield values `a`, `|b.|c.d||`, and `e`

#### update

Thanks for all the comments. I have to give some context to the question. I basically want to mimic javascript syntax

```
a.hello is a["hello"] or a.hello
a.|hello| is a[hello]
a.|b.c.|d.e||.f.|g| is a[b.c[d.e]].f[g]
```

So what I'd want to do is to break the symbols into:

```
 [`a`, `|b.c.|d.e||`, `f`, `|g|`]
```

and then recur through them if they are pipe-quoted

I've got an implementation of the syntax without pipes here:

https://github.com/zcaudate/purnam

I'm really hoping not to use a parser mainly as I don't know how and I don't think it justifies the necessary complexity. But if regex can't cut it, I may have to.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: clojure... but I was hoping just to use regex

Comment: What you said isn't true `regular expression can be used to write checkers that check for pairs of start and end`, not all regex flavors can do that. This question seems the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16415558/) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16420841/) uses `(?R)`. Otherwise you have to write [a mini-parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16420497/).

Comment: Clojure uses Java regex, so you can't do bracket matching, since Java regex doesn't support recursive matching.

Comment: @zcaudate "clojure... but I was hoping just to use regex" ... the language you are using is still crucial, because (especially when it comes to the boundaries of what's possible with regex) there are some important differences between regex implementations

Comment: From your examples it seems that `.|` is the real opening bracket (actually: pipe is opening iff preceded by dot.) Without such an additional rule it is not possible at all to figure out the nesting.

Comment: This may or may not be possible with clojure regex, but it will be much easier using a library like [instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse)

Comment: Finding the start and end is within the power of regular expressions. Its the parsing out of nested expressions that requires a stack.

Comment: A. Webb: he claims that his start and end characters are the same symbol, and he is nesting them

Comment: @m.buettner: Can you explain some of the differences?

Comment: @rafal I know what you mean. I'm hoping there's a good way to exploit it. See my comment on A.Webb's  answer

Comment: @zcaudate there are way too many http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html ... in particular only PCRE, .NET and Lua (as far as I know) have any means to detect an arbitrary amount of nesting levels (PCRE with the recursive `(?R)` syntax and .NET through "balancing groups", and Lua through balanced characters). There are several other differences like the availability and power of lookarounds (especially lookbehinds) etc etc. Always quote your language/tool/environment/flavor when asking regex questions.

Comment: @zcaudate regarding the problem, this seems to be really easy to solve by walking the string character by character: you start in splitting mode. if you encounter a `.` split before and after it. if you next encounter a `|` go into `|`-counting mode. at every `.|` you encounter, increment the `depth` by `1`, at every `|.`, decrement by `1`. when the depth counter hits 0 again, go back into splitting mode. I don't know any clojure, so anyone who does, feel free to make this an answer including some code.

Comment: Thanks @m.buettner! I know how to do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @m.buettner and @rafal, this is my code in clojure:

There is a `normal-mode` and `pipe-mode`. Following what m.buettner described:

#### Helpers:

```
(defn conj-if-str [arr s]
  (if (empty? s) arr
      (conj arr s)))

(defmacro case-let [[var bound] & body]
  `(let [~var ~bound]
     (case ~var ~@body)))
```

#### Pipe Mode:

```
(declare split-dotted) ;; normal mode declaration

(defn split-dotted-pipe   ;; pipe mode
  ([output current ss] (split-dotted-pipe output current ss 0))
  ([output current ss level]
      (case-let
       [ch (first ss)]
       nil (throw (Exception. "Cannot have an unpaired pipe"))
       \|  (case level
             0 (trampoline split-dotted
                           (conj output (str current "|"))
                           "" (next ss))
             (recur output (str current "|") (next ss) (dec level)))
       \.  (case-let
            [nch (second ss)]
            nil (throw (Exception. "Incomplete dotted symbol"))
            \|  (recur output (str current ".|") (nnext ss) (inc level))
            (recur output (str current "." nch) (nnext ss) level))
       (recur output (str current ch) (next ss) level))))
```

#### Normal Mode:

```
(defn split-dotted
  ([ss]
     (split-dotted [] "" ss))
  ([output current ss]
     (case-let
      [ch (first ss)]
       nil (conj-if-str output current)
       \.  (case-let
            [nch (second ss)]
            nil (throw (Exception. "Cannot have . at the end of a dotted symbol"))
            \|  (trampoline split-dotted-pipe
                            (conj-if-str output current) "|" (nnext ss))
            (recur (conj-if-str output current) (str nch) (nnext ss)))
       \|  (throw (Exception. "Cannot have | during split mode"))
       (recur output (str current ch) (next ss)))))
```

#### Tests:

```
(fact "split-dotted"
  (js/split-dotted "a") => ["a"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.b") => ["a" "b"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.b.c") => ["a" "b" "c"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.||") => ["a" "||"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b|.c") => ["a" "|b|" "c"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b|.|c|") => ["a" "|b|" "|c|"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b.c|.|d|") => ["a" "|b.c|" "|d|"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b.|c||.|d|") => ["a" "|b.|c||" "|d|"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b.|c||.|d|") => ["a" "|b.|c||" "|d|"]
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b.|c.d.|e|||.|d|") => ["a" "|b.|c.d.|e|||" "|d|"])

(fact "split-dotted exceptions"
  (js/split-dotted "|a|") => (throws Exception)
  (js/split-dotted "a.") => (throws Exception)
  (js/split-dotted "a.|||") => (throws Exception)
  (js/split-dotted "a.|b.||") => (throws Exception))
```