# php replacing text in a template engine

Tags: php, regex, templates, tags, nested

we have a situation where we have a template file like the following

```
<?php
  $tpl = '
    <p>This is the header</p>
    {if "IS VALID"}
      <p>The value is valid
      {if "IS NUMBER"}
        and it is a number
      {/if}
      </p>
    {/if}
 ';

  $is_valid = false;
  $is_number = true;

  if ($is_valid){
    $tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS VALID"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/sU','\1',$tpl);
  }else{
    $tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS VALID"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/sU','',$tpl);
  }

  if ($is_number){
    $tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS NUMBER"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/sU','\1',$tpl);
  }else{
    $tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS NUMBER"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/sU','',$tpl);
  }

  echo $tpl;
?>
```

The problem is that the first replacement, replaces all way to the FIRST {/if} block. We want it to replace the matching {/if}, that is, take into consideration the nesting of {if}s.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will most likely have to code a custom parser, otherwise just use an already made template engine. I think it is possible though using regex, but it's too complex ...

Comment: Well, the custom parser is what I am looking for!

About using an existing template engine: The head of the project thinks that the other template engines are slow since they contain so much bloatware and operations that are never actually used. I have to admin he is right on that...

Comment: Well to write a parser it will take some time, you may get some inspiration and idea how complex it is with [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16420497).

Answer (score 1):

Put this statment first

```
if ($is_number){
    $tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS NUMBER"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/sU','\1',$tpl);
  }else{
    $tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS NUMBER"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/sU','',$tpl);
  }
```

Your have to check the deepest level fisrt like that it will not be overwriten by others

### EDIT:

If you remove 'U' option your regexp will take the latest closing {/if}:

```
$tpl = preg_replace('/\{if "IS VALID"\}(.*)\{\/if\}/s','\1',$tpl);
```

$tp1 will contain:

```
{if "IS VALID"}
<p>The value is valid
{if "IS NUMBER"}
and it is a number
{/if}
</p>
```

witch shoul math your others statment

Comment: Nice one, but sometimes the nesting is too big to actually care for the order ;), let alone the designers dont actually inform you of the way they put the variables!
This should be done automatically!